# How do I translate a regular select statement into a select statement with a nested query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to figure out how to convert a regular select statement into a select statement with a nested query.

```
SELECT showschedule.planno, showrequest.eventno, showdate,genre
FROM showrequest, showschedule, venue
WHERE showschedule.showdate BETWEEN '2001-12-01' AND '2001-12-31'
AND showrequest.eventno = showschedule.eventno
AND showrequest.FacilityNo = venue.FacilityNo
AND venuename = 'House of Blues'
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what would go in the inner query and what would go in the outer query.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? If you describe the reason, it'd be easier to assist,

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: That sounds like an artificial need. The query should be efficient as it is. By the way, please switch to modern join syntax. The comma-separated tables -- from 1989 (the year of the lambada) -- was superseded in 1992.

Comment: Apart from not using modern `join` syntax, the query looks good. What's the actual problem with it?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with rewriting the statement?